# MySQL Select max on multiple values?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

```
file   MajorVersion MinorVersion
a      0            1
b      0            1
a      0            2
a      0            3
b      1            0
a      1            0
b      1            1
```

I would like to get each file's latest version (highest minor version of the highest major version). In this case:

```
a 1 0
b 1 1
```

Its seems possible with two joins and group by file, but I thought there maybe a better way. Maybe by use of having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one join required:

```
SELECT   file, MajorVersion, MAX(MinorVersion) MinorVersion
FROM     my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   file, MAX(MajorVersion) MajorVersion
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY file
) t
GROUP BY file
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a6a2/1/0).

Comment: Thanks, what would be the best way to do it if the table contained heaps of other fields that were also needed?

Comment: @Myforwik: In that case, it is best to introduce a second join.

Answer (score 0):

Two join method is:

```
select t1.* from `table` as t1
JOIN
(
  select `file` , max(`minor`) as `minor` from `table` 
  group by `file` , `major` 
) as t2
on t1.`file` = t2.`file` and t1.`minor` = t2.`minor` and t1.`major` = t2.`major`
JOIN
(
select `file` , max(`major`) as `major` , `minor` from `table` 
group by `file`
)  as t3
on t1.`file = t3.`file` and t1.`major` = t3.`major`
```

Answer (score 0):

No-JOIN version for minor versions below 10:

```
SELECT file, MAX(CAST(CONCAT(Majorversion, '.', MinorVersion) AS DECIMAL(5,1))) as version
FROM my_table
group by file
```

Results:

```
file    version
a       3.0
b       1.1
```

Minor versions >= 10 would need some extra formatting :-)